# Why is Chrome Console returning a stringifyed object?

Tags: javascript, object, google-chrome-devtools

I've never seen this before and there's nothing on the internet that I could find.

I have a submit button and when I click it it's accessing the Clarifai API and returning the output which is an object, but instead of it being a normal object that is organized in chrome console, it's a stringifyed object.

This is fine and all, just makes it harder to find the path I need to get the info I need.

Here is my code:

```
onButtonSubmit = () => {
  console.log('click');
    const USER_ID = 'realvicandy';
    const PAT = '33c27a0a3f2547f789bc36bbdec57dcc';
    const APP_ID = 'my-first-application';
    // Change these to whatever model and image URL you want to use
    const MODEL_ID = 'color-recognition';
    const MODEL_VERSION_ID = 'dd9458324b4b45c2be1a7ba84d27cd04';    
    const IMAGE_URL = 'https://samples.clarifai.com/metro-north.jpg';

    const raw = JSON.stringify({
        "user_app_id": {
            "user_id": USER_ID,
            "app_id": APP_ID
        },
        "inputs": [
            {
                "data": {
                    "image": {
                        "url": IMAGE_URL
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    });

    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Key ' + PAT
        },
        body: raw
    };

    // NOTE: MODEL_VERSION_ID is optional, you can also call prediction with the MODEL_ID only
    // https://api.clarifai.com/v2/models/{YOUR_MODEL_ID}/outputs
    // this will default to the latest version_id

    fetch("https://api.clarifai.com/v2/models/" + 'color-recognition' + "/versions/" + MODEL_VERSION_ID + "/outputs", requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(result => console.log(result))
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Here is the object in chrome:

```
{"status":{"code":10000,"description":"Ok","req_id":"368a54d959cc2cd826ad08d7caa28fac"},"outputs":[{"id":"91e04fc631014d8b804a88859a62ee7b","status":{"code":10000,"description":"Ok"},"created_at":"2022-12-07T18:00:03.033519292Z","model":{"id":"color-recognition","name":"color","created_at":"2016-05-11T18:05:45.924367Z","modified_at":"2022-11-01T19:45:15.089623Z","app_id":"main","output_info":{"message":"Show output_info with: GET /models/{model_id}/output_info"},"model_version":{"id":"dd9458324b4b45c2be1a7ba84d27cd04","created_at":"2016-07-13T01:19:12.147644Z","status":{"code":21100,"description":"Model is trained and ready"},"visibility":{"gettable":50},"app_id":"main","user_id":"clarifai","metadata":{},"output_info":{"message":"Show output_info with: GET /models/{model_id}/output_info"},"input_info":{},"train_info":{},"import_info":{}},"user_id":"clarifai","input_info":{},"train_info":{},"model_type_id":"image-color-recognizer","visibility":{"gettable":50},"metadata":null,"presets":{},"languages":[],"import_info":{},"workflow_recommended":false},"input":{"id":"845ed7176680401cbcefe9e4dd70a19b","data":{"image":{"url":"https://samples.clarifai.com/metro-north.jpg"}}},"data":{"colors":[{"raw_hex":"#513f2c","w3c":{"hex":"#696969","name":"DimGray"},"value":0.14725},{"raw_hex":"#7298e2","w3c":{"hex":"#6495ed","name":"CornflowerBlue"},"value":0.31575},{"raw_hex":"#1e181b","w3c":{"hex":"#000000","name":"Black"},"value":0.20175},{"raw_hex":"#8f714b","w3c":{"hex":"#d2b48c","name":"Tan"},"value":0.1125},{"raw_hex":"#d2c275","w3c":{"hex":"#bdb76b","name":"DarkKhaki"},"value":0.017},{"raw_hex":"#141b3c","w3c":{"hex":"#000000","name":"Black"},"value":0.12},{"raw_hex":"#404b84","w3c":{"hex":"#483d8b","name":"DarkSlateBlue"},"value":0.0705},{"raw_hex":"#e5e1cc","w3c":{"hex":"#faebd7","name":"AntiqueWhite"},"value":0.01525}]}}]}
```

Expect result: return an organized object in chrome console.

Actual Result: return a stringifyed object in chrome console.

Comment: Either use `.json()` instead, or parse the JSON into an object

Comment: Thank you! Using `response.json()` instead of `response.text()` fixed it since .json() parses and resolves to a JS Object as I read on MDN. I just didn't know what to search. If I had it would have been an easy find. Thank you again.